# calculating with data from enums

Tags: java, enums, double, getter

I'm trying to write a getter which takes specific data from an enum and returns a double, which I will use later in my code and I'm not sure how to go about it. This is what I've come up with so far:

```
//This getter takes the enum of Month and converts it so it returns the mean precipitation of a certain month

public double getPrecipitationMonth(Month month){
//more in here
return this.precipitationMonths[month.ordinal()];
```

The enum in question is the months of the year ie {JANUARY, FEBRUARY...} and the data for each month is in a separate file.

I'm new to programming - hope you can help! Thank you

Comment: Could you provide your whole enum?

Comment: Do not use the ordinal. It reserved for JVM. You should add your own id to the structure.

Comment: Presumably as each month rolls by, the precipitation returned for the month just gone will be different, so the values are not constant... So you probably shouldn't be using an array.

Comment: @Bohemian, What does precipitation mean/stand for ?

Comment: Using ordinal is fine, really. Using it in ones own code doesn't interfere with how standard libraries use it in anyways. Then again the point of Enum is kind of that you don't *have* to use ordinals, so  legitimate use should be rare.

Comment: @EnnoShioji, You have right that does not interfere with standards libraries use. But if you are using it it mean that your approach is not proper. That is why you should not use it.

Comment: @vash "precipitation" is a fancy word for "rainfall"

Answer (score 0):

I would write `eum` something like that:

```
public enum Month {
    JAN (1.0),
    FEB (2.0),  
    MAR (3.0);


    private double mId;

    public static Month     fromDoubleToEnum( double value ) throws Exception{
        for ( Month c : Month.values() ) {
            if ( c.mId == value ) {
                return c;
            }
        }

        throw new Exception( "Illegal Month value: " + value );
            }

    public double fromEnumToDouble(){
        return mId;
    }


    private EModule (double num){
        mId = num;
    }
}
```

Here we have method: `fromEnumToDouble` that returns `double` on `enum`.

*Test*

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Month mod = Month.FEB;

    double toDouble = mod.fromEnumToDouble();

    System.out.println(toDouble); // out 2.0
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that those data are runtime constants ?

Comment: @Vash why not, you initiate nothing here, see my edit

Comment: I ref. to the value of `1.0` assigned to January. In OP question is stated that the data are in file.

Answer (score 0):

I think your general idea is very sound. But I'd just use a Map like so:

```
Map<Month,Double> data = new HashMap<>;
for(Row row : readFromFile()){
    data.put(row.getMonth(), row.getData());
}
```

So that it's more obvious.

Comment: Don't use `HashMap`s with `enum`s, use [`EnumMap`s](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html) instead. They're essentially arrays, thus faster.

Comment: @Darkhogg: I agree they are faster, but thought I'd not confuse the OP with different map implementations... (HashMaps are fast enough anyways)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a HashMap for this, assigning enum values as keys

```
enum Month {
    // Your enum
}    

HashMap< Month, Double > monthPrecipitation = new HashMap< Month, Integer >();

public double getPrecipitationMonth( Month month ) {
    return monthPrecipitation.get( month );
}
```

Comment: Don't use `HashMap`s with `enum`s, use [`EnumMap`s](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html) instead. They're essentially arrays, thus faster.

Answer (score 0):

Use an [`EnumMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html) to store your `precipitationMonths` array instead.

```
EnumMap<Month,Something> precipitationMonths = new EnumMap<Month,Something>(Month.class);
precipitationMonths.put(Month.JANUARY, someValue); // Add a value
Something someValue = precipitationMonths.get(Month.JANUARY); // Get a value
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding that your data are located in file you need to create a class that will store that data and be able to map them.

The Java has really poor support for calendar, but you can work with it using [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) class

You can create a enum for calendar but it is not mandatory.

```
 enum Month{
   JANUARY(Calender.JANUARY);

   private final int month;

   Month(int month) {
     this.month = month;
   }

   public int month() {
    return month;
   }
 }
```

When you solve the first problem of matching the data from file with months.

```
 private final Map<Month,Double> precipitationMap = new EnumMap<>();

 private void assignPrecipitation(Month month, double precipitation) {
    this.precipitationMap.put(month,precipitation);
 }

 public double getPrecipitation(Month month) {

   if(this.precipitationMap.contains(month) {
     return this.precipitationMap.get(month).doubleValue();
   }

   throw new IllegalStateException("The Precipitation was not found for: " + myCalendar); 

 }
```